# java substitute for angularJs watch

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, hash

To understand this question one must know the `$watch` module of Angular.

My requirement is to find a substitute of `$watch` of Angular in Java. I have hash table which has over 1000 values. Now every time when a value in hash table changes I want to trigger an event. Now the event must be triggered only when any one value changes in the hash table. Event must not triggered if the hash table is acceded just to read or compare values.

I hope this would pretty must clear out my requirement. I need some hints to start off. Basic ideas or things i could look into for this. If a readily built framework is available then it would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extend the HashTable to override `put` method, somoe thing like below

```
public class CustomMap<K,V> extends Hashtable<K,V> {

     public V put(K key, V value) {
         //perform your operation to register the event
        return super.put(key, value);
     }
}
```

And then you can use your custom map `HashTable tb = new CustomMap();`